# Swift 4 sharing audio file (UIDocumentInteractionController)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, whatsapp

I have this block of code from a previous project, my plan is to send an audio file(mp3) by `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but I specifically need that show also the possibility to share by WhatsApp. Also, I've added a `UIAlertView` which since ios9 has been deprecated. As you probably realized, this code is kind of "old". So I would appreciate it if you could suggest any option to make it work as at the moment since, in swift 4, it doesn't.

```
var documentationInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController? 
    @IBAction func ShareButton(_ sender: Any) {
        do {

            if let aString = URL(string: "whatsapp://app") {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(aString) {

                    var savePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Documents/whatsAppTmp.waa").absoluteString

                    savePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FILENAME", ofType: "mp3") ?? ""

                    documentationInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: savePath))
                    documentationInteractionController?.uti = "net.whatsapp.audio"
                    documentationInteractionController?.delegate = self as? UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

                    documentationInteractionController?.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), in: view, animated: true)
                } else {
                    _ = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "No WhatsApp installed on your iPhone", delegate: (self as! UIAlertViewDelegate), cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "")
                }
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to add WhatsApp in your info.plist file in the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` array so your app will be allowed to query for the scheme whatsapp.

Then here is your code updated for Swift 4.2, the "do" is useless and I use UIAlertController.

```
@IBAction func share(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let aString = URL(string: "whatsapp://app") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(aString) {

            var fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Documents/whatsAppTmp.waa").absoluteString
            fileUrl = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FILENAME", ofType: "mp3") ?? ""

            documentationInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrl))
            documentationInteractionController?.uti = "net.whatsapp.audio"
            documentationInteractionController?.delegate = self

            documentationInteractionController?.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), in: view, animated: true)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "No WhatsApp installed on your iPhone.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler: { _ in
                NSLog("The \"OK\" alert occured.")
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to adopt the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` protocol. I didn't touch the code for your audio file because I know nothing about it.